# How does MapReduce framework implement the sort phase?

Tags: sorting, frameworks, hadoop, mapreduce, implementation

I am interested in the implementation of the MapReduce sort phase; it seems to be very efficient. Could someone provide some references about it please? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce) points to [ReduceTask.java](http://www.javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java.html) as the place where sort phase is coded. See lines 393-408 in [ReduceTask.java](http://www.javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java.html). If you need more info, [download the entire source](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/) and dig into it.

**EDITED**

"Sort" phase falls under ReduceTask as shown in this figure below from [hadoop book](http://www.hadoopbook.com/). (Page no: 163)
[image]

Comment: Attention: The sort happens actually after the mapper. The reducer just merges the sorted segments.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: see the figure above.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut sorting happens over the output of map() method and the inputs that a reducer gets from several mappers. The later is termed as the "Sort Phase" (as shown in the pic).

Comment: the sorting is parallel to the output to map, still the sort phase is just a merge phase. So the naming is misleading. That is what my intention was (a few months ago).