# How to have a shared variable among all reduce jobs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have a 1 TB of unsorted word counts (word:count) and I would like to run a map reduce job that would pick the word with the largest count. In this case, I want to have a variable that is shared among all reduce jobs that will hold the word with the maximum word count so far. The reduce function will just check this variable and update it if necessary. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: see if this answer helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048013/sharing-data-between-master-and-reduce/15073701#15073701

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how Mapreduce works. It precisely doesn't share memory between machines in order to increase throughput, although you are limited by the mechanism of the Mapreduce model.

In order to do what you're saying, you would do the following:

```
Map : (word, count) -> (KEY_CONSTANT, (count, word))
```

And

```
Combine/Reduce : (key, List<(count, word)>) -> (key, (count*, word*) with max count)
```

If you add `count` to the key, but ensure that everything is still in one partition, you can tell MapReduce to sort the keys by `count` descending, then you can implement a separate reducer that just examines the first value in each list. However, you can't do this for the combiner, the input of which isn't sorted. Might make things quite a bit faster in implementation since it won't read the rest of that data.

For more information on how to use the sort phase effectively, see **[How does MapReduce framework implement the sort phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363761/how-does-mapreduce-framework-implement-the-sort-phase)**

General description of the procesS: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce

Answer (score 2):

You could

- set the number of reducers to 1
- add two instance variables to the reducer class, one for the count and one for the word, to hold information about the most frequent word yet.
- initialize the variables in the reduce setup() method
- in the reduce() method check to see if the current word has occurred more than the most frequent-to-date and if so, store the word and count in the variables
- in the cleanup() method you can access the variables to have the most frequent word

If you need to run multiple reducers, then modify the reducer's cleanup() method to instead write out the word and its count to the context as a key-value pair.  A follow-on reducer similar to the original reducer above can easily find the word with the most occurrences.